# syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting LEFT_PAREN

Tags: glsl, vulkan

```
struct voxel {
    vec3 center;
    vec3 quaternion;
    vec4 color;
    float specular;
    float reflective;
};
```

> 

```
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) buffer Data {
    voxel world[];
};
```

> 

```
vec2 boxCol(vec3 rc, vec3 rd, vec3 vCord, out vec3 vnorm) {...
```

> 

```
vec2 it = boxCol(rc, rd, world[i].center, vec3 vnorm); //bug here
```

syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting LEFT_PAREN

That's my bug^. I'm a beginner in Vulkan and can't find anything to help me figure out what the problem is. OpenGL GLSL differs at least in reading data from a buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Oh well, how could it be otherwise. In general, my mistake is that I initialize a variable in a function call. So the correct one looks like this:

```
vec3 vnorm;
vec2 it = boxCol(rc, rd, world[i].center, vnorm);
```